# Failed to convert value of type java.util.ArrayList to String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

If I add a Section in this database it says "Failed to convert the value of type java.util.ArrayList to String"
I am using recyclerviewoption query to display only the current user data.

I need to display the child "List".

Firebase User:

```
"Users":{
   "I50JqiuTcXfPR7e6poegk3wnIjp2":{
      "List":[
         1,
         {
            "Sections":"1-1"
         }
      ],
      "Password":"Randomber16",
      "email":"arzz.srosarda@gmail.com",
      "fullName":"Sean Harvey C. Rosarda ",
      "uid":"I50JqiuTcXfPR7e6poegk3wnIjp2",
      "usertype":"Instructor"
   }
```

Main Activity

```java
 sectionIn = view.findViewById(R.id.SectionIn);
        add = view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        recview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recview);
        recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reference.child(user.getUid()).child("List").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String section = sectionIn.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

                        if (snapshot.exists()){
                            maxid = (snapshot.getChildrenCount());
                        }
                            snapshot.getRef().child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).child("Sections").setValue(section);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

MyAdapter

```java
 public SectionsAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelUsers> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull ModelUsers model) {
        holder.sectionTv.setText(model.getList());

        holder.cardv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (model.getList().equals("1-1")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragment.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                } else if (model.getList().equals("1-2")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC2.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                } else if (model.getList().equals("1-3")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC3.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-4")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC4.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-5")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC5.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-6")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC6.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-7")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC7.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-8")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC8.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-9")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC9.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-10")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC10.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-11")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC11.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-12")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC12.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-13")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC13.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-14")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC14.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }else if (model.getList().equals("1-15")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), I_MainFragmentC15.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                } else if (model.getList().isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

MyModelUser

```java
public class ModelUsers {

    String List;
    String fullName;
    String yearSection;
    String email;
    String Password;
    String uid;
    String usertype;
    String studentNumber;

    String week2score, week3score, week4score, week5score, week6score, week7score, week8score, week10score, week11score, week12score, week13score, week14score, week15score, week16score, week17score;



    public ModelUsers() {
    }

    public ModelUsers(String List, String fullName, String yearSection, String email, String password, String uid, String usertype,String studentNumber, String week2score, String week3score, String week4score, String week5score, String week6score, String week7score, String week8score, String week10score, String week11score, String week12score, String week13score, String week14score, String week15score, String week16score, String week17score) {
        this.List = List;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.yearSection = yearSection;
        this.email = email;
        Password = password;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.usertype = usertype;
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
        this.week2score = week2score;
        this.week3score = week3score;
        this.week4score = week4score;
        this.week5score = week5score;
        this.week6score = week6score;
        this.week7score = week7score;
        this.week8score = week8score;
        this.week10score = week10score;
        this.week11score = week11score;
        this.week12score = week12score;
        this.week13score = week13score;
        this.week14score = week14score;
        this.week15score = week15score;
        this.week16score = week16score;
        this.week17score = week17score;
    }

    public String getList() {
        return List;
    }

    public void setList(String list) {
        List = list;
    }
```

I tried adding the "long mxid=0;" to add 1 in every section. then I don't know why it shows that error.

Comment: The screenshot you have provided is not complete. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact data you want to read/update.

Comment: Sorry for the Error I already edited my codes

Comment: Aside from my answer, when it comes to **arrays** in the Realtime Database, there are some things you need to take into consideration. So I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-realtime-database-to-a-list-of-objects-53f27b33c8f3) will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> Failed to convert the value of type java.util.ArrayList to String

Because the type of the `List` field in your database is an array, while in your `ModelUsers` class is a String, hence the error. If you need the field to be a String, as it is in the class, then you have to change the field in the database to be a String and not an array. On the other hand, if you need the field to be an array, then you have to change the field in the database to be a `List<WhateverObjectYouHaveThere>`.

Comment: Hey Sean. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

your database is in the form of an array and the user class is a string